# Why is this clean filter being ignored the first time it runs?

Tags: git, gitattributes

In an attempt to automatically make `.sh` files executable on commit, I made a clean filter and was confused by its results.

First, I ran `git config filter.executable.clean 'chmod +x %f'`. This adds the following stanza to my test repository's `.git/config` file:

```
[filter "executable"]
        clean = chmod +x %f
```

Next I created a `.gitattributes` file:

```
*.sh    filter=executable
```

Let's see how this behaves. Of course, a newly-created `.sh` file isn't executable:

```
$ touch foo.sh
$ ls -l foo.sh
-rw-r--r-- foo.sh
```

If we `add` it our clean filter should run. But this results in an executable file in our working directory, a *non-executable* file in our staging area, and a dirty working copy!

```
$ git add foo.sh
$ ls -l foo.sh  # As expected
-rwxr-xr-x foo.sh
$ git ls-files -s foo.sh  # Confusing
100644 foo.sh
$ git status  # Confusing
Changes to be committed:
  new file: foo.sh

Changes not staged for commit:
  modified: foo.sh
```

Running `git add` again results in an executable file in the staging area and a clean working copy:

```
$ git add foo.sh
$ git ls-files -s foo.sh
10755 foo.sh
$ git status
Changes to be committed:
  new file: foo.sh
```

What's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git's filters must [take their input from STDIN and send their output to STDOUT](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#__code_filter_code):

> Upon checkout, when the `smudge` command is specified, the command is fed the blob object from its standard input, and its standard output is used to update the worktree file. Similarly, the `clean` command is used to convert the contents of worktree file upon checkin.

The filter shown above doesn't behave this way. It ignores STDIN and it sends no output to STDOUT, so its effect is not captured with the first `git add` command. The staged file is not executable.

However, the filter *does* run. This has the side effect of adding the execute bit on the file in the working copy. `git status` sees that the permissions on the file have changed.

The second `git add` captures the executable bit, but not directly because of our filter. It simply stages the permission changes it sees in the working copy.

I am not aware of any way to modify a file's permissions via STDIN and STDOUT. It may be very difficult to modify file permissions in clean and smudge filters.

Comment: Note that your filter could run `git update-index`—delayed if the index is locked now, which it will be—which can change the mode stored in the *index*, which is where Git stores the permissions that will be used on the *next* commit. You would need to both make the file itself executable, and update the index, which will leave you with "changes staged for commit". This violates the *spirit* of filters, but is likely to work as desired.